# Automatically connect IoT devices to a VPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, internet-of-things

So I have this GCP setup with IoT devices, but I want to SSH into devices that are geographically very far. Of course they are not on the same local network. My current idea is that I host a VPN and connect them through it while I am myself a client of this VPN. It works when I use a single device, however the autologin file (openvn.conf, user-locked) seems to only allow one connection and disconnect any other devices. Maybe I am misunderstanding how a VPN works, but how would one go about creating a new user automatically ? Is there anyway to have an autologin file that handles multiple devices ?

I am using OpenVPN Access Server v2.7.5 with a Debian Linux distribution on the devices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know anything about OpenVPN, but VPN's in general usually allow only a single session per user account. Why not use an explicit user account for each device? You could use the device serial number, or some other unique identifier, as the username.

Comment: Yes, but then how do I automate this user process ? These devices are built and configured at a third party so I don't have access to it before they are shipped unfortunately.

Comment: If you don't have access to them how are you configuring them now? Are they preconfigured? If so, how about changing the "build" or configuration process?

Comment: Currently I use the web interface on the go. I could go and check if OpenVPN as an API however. I am more wondering if VPN servers have mechanisms for this kind of use case.